# How to calculate how long (in seconds) between two user inputs?

Tags: java, eclipse

How would you calculate the difference in time between when the user presses enter the first time and when they press enter the second time. I have looked through stack overflow questions that show the difference between two dates but I am not sure how to do it in this circumstance.

```
int TimeOne;
int TimeTwo;
int Answer;

System.out.print("What is 5 + 10? (Please press enter to start the timer)")
Answer = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Comment: Is going to be hard to help you if you dont provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)...

Comment: When the user clicks enter you create a Date and get the time that the user crliced, and then, when the user clicks the second time, you compare that date with the time in that moment, i think this will work

Comment: @FranciscoMelicias Doesn't have to be a `Date`. Keeping a `long` measured with `System.currentTimeMillis()` would be enough.

Comment: i said the Date because he said that he already tried to use Date, but, thats an excellent idea!!

Comment: For Java 8 `Instant` and `Duration` might be the things to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by greg-449 Instant and Duration can be used as in:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;

...

Instant start = Instant.now()

// here waiting for user input, very simplified, just an example
System.in.read();

Instant end = Instant.now();
Duration duration = Duration.between(start, end);
```

Any of the various methods of Duration can then be used as needed. Example to get the duration in seconds:

```
int seconds = duration.getSeconds();
```